# Parsing XML message

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm attempting to parse the following XML:

```
<marketstat><type id="18">
      <buy><volume>33000000</volume><avg>40.53</avg><max>65.57</max><min>6.55</min><stddev>26.61</stddev><median>58.56</median><percentile>65.57</percentile></buy>
      <sell><volume>494489</volume><avg>69.47</avg><max>69.47</max><min>69.47</min><stddev>0.00</stddev><median>69.47</median><percentile>69.47</percentile></sell>
      <all><volume>33494489</volume><avg>40.96</avg><max>69.47</max><min>6.55</min><stddev>26.77</stddev><median>58.56</median><percentile>6.55</percentile></all>
    </type><type id="19">
      <buy><volume>270000</volume><avg>1707.31</avg><max>3549.38</max><min>239.74</min><stddev>1554.26</stddev><median>239.75</median><percentile>3549.34</percentile></buy>
      <sell><volume>48599</volume><avg>24930.45</avg><max>29869.95</max><min>5200.00</min><stddev>9875.66</stddev><median>29869.93</median><percentile>5232.20</percentile></sell>
      <all><volume>280926</volume><avg>1957.07</avg><max>10750.00</max><min>239.74</min><stddev>3352.87</stddev><median>1874.31</median><percentile>239.74</percentile></all>
    </type></marketstat>
</evec_api>
```

The pieces of information that I want to retrieve are the minimum sell and maximum buy values, associated with the ID, found here: `<sell><min>69.47</min></sell>`.

I'm currently using the following to get the XML: `marketData = Nokogiri::XML(open(api))`

Comment: What is your question? You need to show us your actual attempt of solving the problem, or show us all the places you've searched and explain why they didn't help. As is you haven't showed us your research or effort. Read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421, "[mcve]" and "[ask]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`xpath`](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) to pull out the nodes of interest, then convert them to `Float`s and pick the value you want. The path to your minimum sell node is `/marketstat/type/sell/min`, or if you want to use shorthand, `//` says "anywhere in the document", so you can specify just `//sell/min` to get all of the minimum sell nodes and `//buy/max` to get all of the maximum buys.

```
sells = market_data.xpath('//sell/min').map(&:content).map(&:to_f)
buys = market_data.xpath('//buy/max').map(&:content).map(&:to_f)

puts sells.min, buys.max
```

Comment: A mixture of both answers is what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following will print the ID and its corresponding min/max:

```
marketData = Nokogiri::XML(open(api))
marketData.xpath("//type").each do |i|
    puts "#{i.attr('id')}: #{i.xpath('.//max').map {|j| j.text.to_f}.max}"
    puts "#{i.attr('id')}:  #{i.xpath('.//min').map {|j| j.text.to_f}.min}"
end
```

Output:

```
18: 69.47
18:  6.55
19: 29869.95
19:  239.74
```

Comment: A mixture of both answers is what I needed. Thank you.